# How to parse inner JSON using GSON builder

Tags: android, gson

My JSON like this:-

```
 {
    "status": "approved",
    "work_flow": {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "xgfdhx",
        "role": "xfhxfhg",
        "user_image": null
    }

 }
```

And my GsonCode is this:-

```
EmployeeDTO eDTO = gson.fromJson(json, eDTO.class);
```

so

```
Log.d(TAG,"Response: "+eDTO.getStatus())-----o/p:- Approved
```

means I am successfully get the status but I had problem to iterate the inner JSON,
Can someone explain me or help me how to get the work_flow inner JSON data.
using GSON builder?

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Change this line `EmployeeDTO eDTO = gson.fromJson(json, eDTO.class);` to

```
EmployeeDTO eDTO = gson.fromJson(json, EmployeeDTO.class);
```

**2.** Add class **EmployeeDTO.java**

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

    String status;

    @SerializedName("work_flow")
    WorkFlow workFlow;
}
```

**3.** Add class **WorkFlow.java**

```
public class WorkFlow {

    int id;
    String name;
    String role;
    String userImage;
}
```